# getting the error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c, identifier

Getting this error : `expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token` on the first bracket after the `#include` before the `int main`. No clue why! Doing an assignment for an introductory programming course. It's due today so any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
{
int main(void);

int cardNum(int firstCard, int secondCard; 
int highLow;
int score;

score = 0;   
srand(time(NULL));

    printf("The current card is a %d\n" ,firstCard(2,14));
    printf("\n Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
    scanf("%d" ,highLow);
if cardNum > 1 && cardNum < 11
{        
     printf ("The card is: %d ,secondCard.");
}        
else if cardNum == 11
{
if highLow == 1, && secondCard > firstCard OR highLow == 2, && secondCard < firstCard
    {   
        score = score + 1; 
        printf ("\n You have guessed correctly.");
        printf ("\n Your current score is %d ,score!\n");
        printf("The current card is a ("%d" ,cardOne). \n Will the next card be           higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
    }    
else if highLow == 1, && secondCard < firstCard OR highLow == 2, && secondCard > firstCard  
    {
        score = score - 1;
        printf ("The card is: %d ,secondCard.");
        printf ("\n You have guessed incorrectly.");
        printf ("\n Your current score is %d ,score!\n");
        printf ("The current card is a %d ,cardOne."); 
        printf ("\n Will the next card be higher(1) or lower(2)? (press 0 to quit)");
    }
else if secondCard == firstCard
    {
        printf ("\n Matching cards, no change in score");
    }
else if highLow == 0
    {
        printf ("\n Thanks for playing! Your final score is %d, score.");
    }
else
    {
        printf ("\n Incorrect input. Please enter 0, 1 or 2")       
    }
}    
return(0);
}
```

I initially had it like that with int main(void){ but then I was getting all these errors instead so I changed it to the semicolon and only got that one error.
a3.c: In function ‘main’:
a3.c:24:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘score’
a3.c:25:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘srand’
a3.c:27:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘printf’
a3.c:28:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘printf’
a3.c:29:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘scanf’
a3.c:31:5: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘if’
a3.c:82:1: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘}’ token
a3.c:82:1: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘}’ token
a3.c:82:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input
a3.c:82:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]

Comment: Remove the ; after `int main(void)`

Comment: {
int main(void);   ===>  int main(void) {

Comment: also `if cardNum > 1 && cardNum < 11` should be `if (cardNum > 1 && cardNum < 11)`

Comment: Yeah, fix that. You will be posting another question soon.

Comment: There are many errors in this program. The one your compiler reports is just the first one.

Comment: I initially had it like that with int main(void){ but then I was getting all these errors instead so I changed it to the semicolon and only got that one error.

Comment: This is one good reason to start adding the opening brace right after the function, instead of on a new line. At a glance it's not something to see easy, especially when there are so many brace pairs, without empty lines separating them. If you want to use the same brace pattern you may want to at least sacrifice another line to cater to this issue as well.

Answer (score 7):

```
{
int main(void);
```

should be

```
int main(void)
{
```

Then I let you fix the next compilation errors of your program...

Answer (score 4):

you need to place the opening brace after `main` , not before it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
```

Comment: There should not be a semi colon after `main`.

Comment: sorry for that @Kunal forgot to remove it